# how to align actionbar title to center in android?

Tags: android

I have used this code,it works fine for single activity but in my application I have number of activities for which I want diffrent titles. May i need to create separate layout file for each activity or there is other approach??

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:text="YOUR ACTIVITY TITLE"
 android:textColor="#ffffff"
 android:textSize="24sp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try This 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="YOUR ACTIVITY TITLE"
 android:textColor="#ffffff"
 android:textSize="24sp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you look at code that I have used it's same as you are telling. This works fine for single activity but in my app there near about 15 activities then how can I use same layout file to change title of each activity as per my application requirement????